# How transform this integral to the "Cauchy's integral"

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I would like to know is there any tricks to transform this 
$$\frac { 1 }{ 2\pi  } \int _{ -\pi  }^{ \pi  }{ \frac { f\left( t \right)  }{ { e }^{ -it }-{ e }^{ ix } } dt } $$ integral to the $$\frac { 1 }{ 2\pi i } \int _{ \gamma  }^{  }{ \frac { f\left( t \right)  }{ t-\xi  } dt } $$
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with

$$\dfrac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma}{\dfrac{g\left(z\right)}{z-\xi}dz}$$

make the substitutions

$$\xi = e^{-ix}$$
$$g(z) = -e^{-ix}f\left(-i\log\left(z\right)-2k\pi\right)$$

and specify the contour as a path on the unit circle from an angle of $-\pi$ to an angle of $\pi$

$$z= e^{it} \quad -\pi \le t \lt \pi$$
$$dz = ie^{it}dt$$

so

$$\begin{align*} \dfrac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma}{\dfrac{g\left(z\right)}{z-\xi}dz} &= \dfrac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma}{\dfrac{-e^{-ix}f\left(-i\log\left(z\right)-2k\pi\right)}{z-e^{-ix}}dz}\\
\\
&= \dfrac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{\dfrac{-e^{-ix}f\left(-i\log\left(e^{it}\right)-2k\pi\right)ie^{it}}{e^{it}-e^{-ix}}dt}\\
\\
&= \dfrac{1}{2\pi } \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{\dfrac{f\left(-i\log\left(e^{it}\right)-2k\pi\right)}{e^{-it}-e^{ix}}dt}\\
\\
&= \dfrac{1}{2\pi } \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{\dfrac{f\left(-i\left[\ln|1|+i(t+2k\pi)\right]-2k\pi\right)}{e^{-it}-e^{ix}}dt}\\
\\
&= \dfrac{1}{2\pi } \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{\dfrac{f\left(t\right)}{e^{-it}-e^{ix}}dt}\\
\end{align*}$$

If you elect to work with the principal branch of the complex logarithm, then you can just set $k=0$ and use $\mathrm{Log}()$ instead of $\log()$.